# strtok problem in visual c++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I am trying the strtok in visual c++, but it seems not working. This not my first time using strtok, but i just counldnt figure out what is wrong with it. the code is quite simple.

in main

```
 cout<<getLevels("/'Group'/'Channel1'")<<endl;
```

in getLevels()

```
int getLevels(char * fullPath){
 int level=0;
 char *nextToken;
 char * pch=strtok_s(fullPath, "/", &nextToken);// broken at here
 while(pch!=NULL){
  level++;
  cout<<level<<":"<<pch<<endl;
  pch=strtok_s(NULL, "/",&nextToken);
 }
 return level;

}
```

it breaks at line

```
 char * pch=strtok_s(fullPath, "/", &nextToken);
```

with error:

```
Unhandled exception at 0x10273de8 (msvcr100d.dll) in tdmsTest.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x0041c840.
```

and the cursor is pointing to this line in strtok_s.ini

```
 for ( ; *str != 0 ; str++ )
    {
        if (map[*str >> 3] & (1 << (*str & 7)))
        {
            *str++ = 0; // pointing here
            break;
        }
    }
```

i tried it in strtok() instead of strtok_s() before, but it has the same problem.
can any one tell me what is wrong with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Strtok is trying to split the string by inserting nulls in place of the tokens.  I'd guess that the literal "/'Group'/'Channel1'" is stored as a constant and can't be modified.

Try removing the "Enable String Pooling (/GF)" flag from the compiler options.

Comment: thank you. you are right. after i change to  
char * temp=strdup("/'Group'/'Channel1'");
 cout<<getLevels(temp)<<endl;
it works.
thanks

Answer (score 4):

The `strtok()` function will *modify* it's argument. You're calling it on a string literal, which is typically in read-only storage.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you're using stroke.  Stop doing that!!!  Strokes are bad for the mind.  Use [Boost.Tokenizer](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_42_0/libs/tokenizer/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

i have problem in my visual studio when i run my program in terminal show this message :
gcc -o xx xx.c
C:/TDM-GCC-64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/10.3.0/../../../../x86_64-w64-mingw32/bin/ld.exe: cannot open output file xx.exe: Permission denied
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30622396)